# Alternatives for categorical prediction

Tags: predictive-modeling, random-forest

#### Upfront question:

> What are some alternative methods for predicting categorical data?

#### Details:

I routinely process data that is 100% categorical. Almost always, this data is nominal (while, occasionally ordinal data such as 'quarters' may be included). When the time comes to run predictive modeling, I feel boxed-in to utilize only one method: [multinomial regression models](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/).

I have yet to have success employing randomForest or decision trees due to the amount of levels for the data (e.g., some variables have upwards of 111 levels in a set of 12000 observations).

I understand that, given the restricted data type, my options will be limited. However, I am wondering if anyone else has created predictive models with (only) nominal data and what method was chosen.

> > Note: I utilize R [3.6.1] for processing and modeling.

Comment: Naive Bayes and SVM come to mind, but I'm not sure they would do better than random forests.

Comment: Yeah man, NB returns 83%. I wonder if there is a variable throwing this off..look at the data shows that, from the confusion matrix, one variable accounts for 55% of the 'Wrong' pred.

Comment: This is interesting, because it means that it predicts reasonably well the other variables. That makes me think that you could try a simple multi-classifier approach: you train a few different classifiers (e.g multinomial, NB, SVM, Random Forests...) and use majority voting on their result.

Comment: You were right in your thinking. Removing the variable increased the model accuracy (bayes) to 96%. I do not like the idea of removing an entire variable though. Especially in this case as it is a grouping variable (ie it is a group identifier, similar to SUV for multiple types of suv models if that makes sense)

Comment: I agree that removing variables for this kind of reason is probably a bad idea. NB is known to be very prone to overfitting. However it can still be useful as part of a set of heterogeneous classifiers, as different classifiers will make different mistakes. You could have a features selection stage for each classifier. Then you could use majority voting or a linear classifier on top of these. It can improve performance but there is a bigger risk of overfitting.

Answer (score 0):

There are many supervised machine learning algorithms for classfication.

Here is a list to get you started:

- Tree-based

  - Decision trees
  - Random Forest
  - Boosted Trees
- Naive Bayes (NB)
- K-nearest neighbors algorithm (k-NN)
- Support vector machines (SVM)
- Neural Networks / Deep Learning (DL)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to solve this problem. You can stick with traditional algorithms like k-NN and play around with the distance metric. If you encode all your data with one-hot encoding you can use manhattan distance with k-NN and see if it solves your problem. Second, you could try playing around with the encoding scheme, there are better ways to encode categorical data https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/ is one of my favorite library for this task, it has many methods implemented. You could still use Random forest and end up building a decent model.